# Dependency injection in a custom Laravel Validator class which extends LaravelValidator

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, laravel-4

I need to gain access to Db repositories inside some validation methods in a custom Laravel Validator class which extends LaravelValidator. How to get it?

My class constructor:

```
<?php namespace Pongo\Cms\Support\Validators;

use Illuminate\Validation\Validator as LaravelValidator;
use Pongo\Cms\Support\Repositories\PageRepositoryInterface as Page;
use Pongo\Cms\Support\Repositories\ElementRepositoryInterface as Element;

class PongoValidator extends LaravelValidator {

    /**
     * Class constructor
     * @param Page    $page 
     * @param Element $element
     */
     public function __construct($translator, $data, $rules, $messages, Page $page, Element $element)
     {
         $this->page = $page;
         $this->element = $element;
     }

     [...]
```

and my Validator resolver (as on Laravel docs):

```
<?php

/**
 * Instantiate CustomValidator class
 */
Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
{
    return new Pongo\Cms\Support\Validators\PongoValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
});
```

How to make it work?
Thanks

Comment: Could you please explain what is going wrong right now? What exactly doesn't work? What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 6):

Ok... I found a solution.

My class constructor:

```
<?php namespace Pongo\Cms\Support\Validators;

use Pongo\Cms\Support\Repositories\PageRepositoryInterface as Page;
use Pongo\Cms\Support\Repositories\ElementRepositoryInterface as Element;

use Illuminate\Validation\Validator as LaravelValidator;

use Config, Media, Str;

class PongoValidator extends LaravelValidator {

    private $page;

    private $element;

/**
 * Class constructor
 * @param Page    $page 
 * @param Element $element
 */
public function __construct($translator, $data, $rules, $messages, Page $page, Element $element)
{
    $this->translator = $translator;
    $this->data = $data;
    $this->rules = $this->explodeRules($rules);
    $this->messages = $messages;

    $this->page = $page;
    $this->element = $element;
}

[...]
```

and my Validator resolver (with IoC on rescue!!):

```
<?php

use Pongo\Cms\Support\Validators\PongoValidator;

/**
 * Instantiate CustomValidator class
 */
Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
{
    $page = App::make('Pongo\Cms\Support\Repositories\PageRepositoryInterface');

    $element = App::make('Pongo\Cms\Support\Repositories\ElementRepositoryInterface'));

    return new PongoValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages, $page, $element);
});
```

Hope it could help anyone else...
Bye

Comment: what is your file path for your validator::resolver? Where did you place it?

Comment: you should mark your questions as answered. @user9507 you can place it anywhere. I added a "validations.php" file in the same directory as routes.php and "require app_path().'/validations.php'" it in global.php. I'm sure there are better ways.

Comment: also, I use parent::__construct(...) so use the code already tested. Its a few lines not copy/pasted.

Comment: Validator::resolver goes in App\Providers\ValidatorServiceProvider